# How to extract number within but excluding brackets with str_extract() from package stringr?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

There are plenty of regex questions out there but I cannot solve the following in a elegant way.

I have the following vector and would like to extract **only the numbers wihtin the square brackets**, that is, excluding the brackets themselves. The numbers may be negative. The question might also be:

**How to extract only the [first capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/3mYOMd/1) with the function `str_extract` from the `{stringr}` package?**

```r
string <- c("[1] cate 1", "[-1] cate -1", "[2] cate 2")
stringr::str_extract(string = string, pattern =  "\\[[^:digit:]+\\]")

[1] "[1]"  "[-1]" "[2]" 

stringr::str_extract(string = string, pattern =  "\\[[^(:digit:)]+\\]")

[1] "[1]"  "[-1]" "[2]"
```

I also tried to append `\\1` to the pattern in order to extract the first group and got the following error:

```r
stringr::str_extract(string = string, pattern =  "\\[[^(?:digit:)]+\\]\\1")

Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Back-reference to a non-existent capture group. (U_REGEX_INVALID_BACK_REF)
```

I appreciate your time and apologize if this question is a duplicate.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(string, "(?<=\\[)-?\\d+(?=\\])")`, see https://ideone.com/DJyBRM

Comment: Great! This does the job. Thank you! (Do you want to write it up as an answer so that I can close the question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
stringr::str_extract(string, "(?<=\\[)-?\\d+(?=\\])")
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/DJyBRM)

If you need to match integer or float numbers, you can use

```r
stringr::str_extract(string, "(?<=\\[)-?\\d*\\.?\\d+(?=\\])")
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=\[)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `[`
- `-?` - an optional `-` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\d*\.?\d+` - matches zero or more digits, an optional `.` and then one or more digits
- `(?=\])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with `]`.